# I have changed my DB version MariaDB to MySQL but my date format is not working properly and showing always 01-01-1970. How can I get rid of this?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have changed my DB version MariaDB to MySQL but my date format is not working properly and showing always 01-01-1970. How can I get rid of this ?

before conversion of DB it was working fine. what should I need more to do ?

I am working on codeignitor with this query. Please check .

```
 $created = $this->Common_model->getAllData('certificate_master', 'created', true, ['id' => $lastId])->created;
                $timestamp = strtotime($created);
                $createdNew = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
```

$createdNew  is always returning 01-01-1970.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's because your 3rd line is calling `$createdNew = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);`, which basically ask for date in 'd-m-Y' format, a.k.a. dd-mm-yyyy. If you want yyyy-mm-dd then change that line into `$createdNew = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);`. This have nothing to do with database

Comment: What does `$created` contain?

Comment: Actually I want in d-m-Y format which is correct. It was working already fine before. but now its not .

Comment: $created contains date retrieved from DB using query.

Comment: @chgav007 yes, but show the contents of that field so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Actually $lastId is query last inserted id. when I am using hardcoded value then it showing data but not when I am using $lastId dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. Actually here when we are creating last inserted id it was going to work after delay with some seconds so I used function sleep() for three seconds delay like sleep(3) after generation of $lastId;

```
$lastId = $this->db->insert_id();
                sleep(3);
                $created = $this->Common_model->getAllData('certificate_master', 'created', true, ['id' => $lastId])->created;
               
                $timestamp = strtotime($created);
                $createdNew = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
```